# Using standalone jars with android studio app engine + gradle

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an app engine project created via the wizard in android studio. The generated build.gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib', include: ['*.jar'])
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
    ...
```

I have put a standalone jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder. I rebuild / refresh gradle, but android studio can't seem to see the classes in the jar file.

Is there something else we need to add to the dependencies closure to make the jar classes accessible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add `src` to your path

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib', include: ['*.jar'])
```